# Sitecore check if Rendering item initialized

Tags: model-view-controller, sitecore

I have a master layout which contains header and footer information. Also, I have pages using specific rendering items with the master layout. If the page using specific rendering items renders, the Title in master layout should be changed from default Title value.

This is my pseudo-code.

```cs
namespace renderingItem1    

public override void Initialize(Rendering rendering)
{
    //code here
}

public string anotherMethod()
{
    string str = "";
    if (Initialized == true) {
        str = "Rendering Item is called in this page";   
    }
    return str;
}


// In another project, added 'renderingItem1.dll' into references in abother project 
// this is masterLayout.cshtml

@using renderingItem1

@string pageTitle = "";
@if (redneringItem1.anotherMethod() is NOT empty) {

    pageTitle = redneringItem1.anotherMethod();
}
```

In masterLayout.cshtml, it always outputs the default which is `str = ""`

Comment: you should rather post what you want to achieve. I have no idea what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: After @Marek will respond you to the second question, you will add more questions to this post ? :D

Comment: @SitecoreClimber and Marek, I updated and please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: This question is now completely different from the original one. My answer (which was correct initially), has absolutely no sense now. That's the reason why you should not do things like "I added another code, what about now?"

Comment: @MarekMusielak Sorry for making confusion. Do you think if there is any way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Add `Initialized` property to your class and set it in `Initialize` to true:

```cs
public bool Initialized { get; set; }

public override void Initialize(Rendering rendering)
{
    Initialized = true;
    ...
}
```

And by the way, your `anotherMethod` cannot be static - if it's static, you cannot access non-static `Initialized` property and you won't be able to detect what is the status of the current instance of your rendering.